# if statement syntax Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, if-statement

I'm trying to translate some Matlab code into Python. Unfortunately I don't have Matlab so I can't try out the syntax.

I'm confused about an if statement below

```
for i = 1:200
    if mod(i,10) == 0 
        i 
    end
```

The for loop then carries on to calculate some values which depend on i. What does the if statement do?

Can I also ask what the difference between a sparse matrix and one made with zeros eg

```
A = sparse(n,m)
B = zeros(n,m)
```

Thanks!

Comment: For future ref, if you can't get a MATLAB license, or for a quick hack, you might want to try octave, a freeware clone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is usually better to create seperate questions, but I will try to address both:

**1)** The [`mod`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html) function performes the modulo operation, i.e. the remainder after division. `mod(i,10) == 0` will be 1 if a number is divisible by 10, and 0 otherwise. The if statement will therefore be executed when the number i is a multiple of 10.

As there is no `else`part, nothing happens if the condition isn't true.

By just writing `i` (without semicolon), the current value of `i` is printed to the command window. The output of your example code will therefore be `10`, `20`, ..., `200`.

**2)** The `zeros` command creates a "normal" matrix of (of course) zeros of dimension `n x m`. MATLAB also has a special  [sparse memory organization](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/computational-advantages.html). As sparse matrices consist mostly of zeros, you don't need to fill the memory with all those zeros, but you can save the non-zero values and where they are. This is automatically done using the [`sparse`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) function. To convert a sparse matrix to the "normal" format, you can use the [`full`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/full.html) function.

Answer (score 1):

The `if` statement checks whether the [*modulus*](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html) (remainder after division) of i divided by 10 is 0 or not. 
When it is evaluated true, it prints the number `i` to the command window.

Comment: Thanks, does that mean that the rest of the for loop only runs if i is divisible by 10? The real part I didn't understand is what the i in the if statements is doing, and what happens when the if statement isn't true

Comment: If the `if` statement isn't true, nothing happens. If the `if` statement is true, the line below the `if` statement is executed before going to the next number in the `for` loop.

Comment: But in this situation all the if statement executes is 'i', which is already defined from the for loop counter. I don't understand what difference the if statement makes, whether it is true or false. This is someone else code I'm trying to understand.

Answer (score 1):

The naive Python translation would be

```
for i in range(1, 201):
    if not i % 10:
        print(i)
```

but we can save some work by specifying a step value,

```
for i in range(10, 201, 10):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation for `mod`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html). `mod(i,10)` returns the remainder after division of `i` by `10`, where `i` is the dividend and `10` is the divisor. The `if` statement checks whether that remainder is equal to `0` or not.